# oracle date conversion error

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I get an error when the  input for  iv_from_date is given in this format 04/01/2013,it works perfectly when the input is in this format 04/Jan/2013.the nls date format is DD-MON_RR.My input should be in this format 04/01/2013.How do i do this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Sp_SaveNewTaxPercentage(iv_category_id    number,
                                                    iv_tax_percentage number,
                                                    iv_from_date      varchar2,
                                                    iv_to_date        varchar2 default '12/31/9998',
                                                    iv_created_date   date,
                                                    ov_err_code       out nocopy varchar2,
                                                    ov_err_msg        out nocopy varchar2) is
  lv_category_id    varchar2(25);
  LV_TO_DATE        varchar2(25);
  lv_cat_id         varchar2(12);
  IV_TAX_ID         VARCHAR2(12);
  lv_tax_percentage varchar(20);
begin
  ov_err_code := 0;

  SELECT MAX(TAX_ID)
    INTO IV_TAX_ID
    FROM TAX_P
   WHERE CATEGORY_ID IN (iv_category_id);

  for J in (SELECT CATEGORY_ID, FROM_DATE, tax_percentage
              FROM TAX_P
             WHERE TAX_ID = IV_TAX_ID) loop

    SELECT to_date(iv_from_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') - 1
      INTO LV_TO_DATE
      FROM DUAL;

    lv_cat_id         := J.CATEGORY_ID;
    lv_tax_percentage := j.tax_percentage;

    begin
      UPDATE TAX_P
         SET TO_dATE = LV_TO_DATE
       WHERE TAX_PERCENTAGE = lv_tax_percentage
         and to_date = iv_to_date;

      commit;

      insert into tax_p
        (TAX_ID,
         CATEGORY_ID,
         TAX_PERCENTAGE,
         FROM_DATE,
         TO_DATE,
         CREATE_DATE)
      values
        (tax_seq.nextval,
         iv_category_id,
         to_char(iv_tax_percentage, '99D99'),
         iv_from_date,
         iv_to_Date,
         sysdate);

      commit;

    end;

  end loop;

  IF LV_CAT_ID IS NULL THEN

    insert into tax_p
      (TAX_ID,
       CATEGORY_ID,
       TAX_PERCENTAGE,
       FROM_DATE,
       TO_DATE,
       CREATE_DATE)
    values
      (tax_seq.nextval,
       iv_category_id,
       to_char(iv_tax_percentage, '99D99'),
       iv_from_date,
       IV_TO_DATE,
       sysdate);

  END IF;

  commit;

  select 'Successfully Saved' into ov_err_msg from dual;

  commit;
Exception
  when others then
    rollback;
    ov_err_code := 1;
    ov_err_msg  := 'Error while saving' || SQLERRM;
end Sp_SaveNewTaxPercentage;
```

Comment: If `iv_from_date` will always be `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` (can't tell which from the 01/04/2013 example), it's best to specifically convert it to a date using `TO_DATE(iv_from_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`. Messing around with `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` can work, but I prefer not to rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid using `VARCHAR2` type for variables and parameters thar are actually of type `DATE`. Oracle tries to convert your varchar parameter to date implicitly. When format is the same as set in `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` it succeeds else it fails. Make both `iv_from_date` and `iv_to_date` typed as `DATE`. If respective columns in table `TAX_P` are typed as `varchar2` then make explicit format conversion in insert statement.

Comment: from_date in tax_p table is in date format.i tried explicit conversion in insert statement using to_date(iv_from_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') but it failed

Comment: As I said above (sure it sounds as obvious and trivial): when you deal with dates treat them as dates. I would suggest you rewrite your code with properly typed variables and then if you have some errors or troubles edit your question or open a new one. When house set on fire there is no place for furniture renovation.